# Save web page from Protractor (Right click -> Save as ... - from page context menu)

Tags: html, angular, protractor

I have problem saving web page automatically during Protractor test execution. I would like to get this context menu during test execution:

[image]

But I am getting this:

[image]

I don't know why this menu is different when opened in Chrome versus opened during test execution. I got this menu with:

```
browser.driver.actions().click(protractor.Button.RIGHT).perform();
```

Problem is that I can't send Ctrl+S command to the driver. I tried with this line of code with no success:

```
browser.actions().keyDown(protractor.Key.CONTROL).sendKeys('s').perform();
```

I get correct menu in Chrome with Ctrl+S, but here I can't send this shortcut key, and what is interesting, Ctrl+A works (all page text is selected), if I write 'a' instead of 's', but with 's' it doesn't work. Also Arrow-Down is not working:

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```

and I can't get focus on correct menu item even when menu is open.

There is also another problem, that page saved with second menu is not complete (HTML is not complete, it is Angular 2 application, and HTML of one component is not included, like it is not rendered). I get full HTML only when page is saved manually in Chrome or if I do it manually during test execution (during long browser.sleep for example).

Because I just want to have page source for further analysis I also tried to get it with:

```
browser.getPageSource().then((src) => {
    let source = src;
});
```

Still, page source was not complete. HTML of one component rendered with ng-switch is missing. I have this piece of code to be sure that Angular rendering is finished:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
```

**My question is:** 
Is there a way to save full page source from Angular 2 application with Protractor?

Comment: I found why I am getting this menu on a second picture. It is because I am doing click on a link. It is now fine. I can see menu from the first picture, but still other problems remain, I can't move my arrow down or save page as a file ...

Comment: browser.driver.findElement(By.css('body')).getAttribute('innerHTML').then(function(s){ console.log(s)})

Comment: It seems it will work, but with this code: browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].innerHTML;', element(by.tagName('body'))).then(
                        (i) =>  {
                            console.log(i);
                        }
                    ); This is because of this: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md Thanks, I will use it!

Comment: @Barney you can post answer and I will accept it!